# Why are closed balls not a topology in a metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Define a closed ball in a metric space $X$ with the metric $\rho$ that has centre a $x$ and radius $r$ as the set $\{y:\rho(x,y)\le r\}$ for $r\ge0$ and $x,y\in X$. Why are arbitrary unions of closed balls not a topology in $X$ but arbitrary unions of open balls are? An open ball is defined as the set $\{y:\rho(x,y)\lt r\}$.

Comment: Arbitrary union of closed set may not even be closed.

Comment: You also have to take finite intersections.

Comment: You should "unaccept" the currently accepted answer since it does not address your question at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $\mathbb{R}$ let $\{r_n\}_{n\in N}\subseteq(0,1)$ be an increasing sequence such that $r_n\rightarrow1$ whenever $n\rightarrow\infty$. The sets $[-r_n,r_n]$ are closed balls in the standar topolgy of $\mathbb{R}$ but $\bigcup_{n\in N}[-r_n,r_n]=(-1,1)$.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question at all. You've shown a union of closed balls can be an open set in the standard topology on $\mathbb R$. That doesn't rule out that it could define a topology?

Comment: This does not address the question at all. It does not even qualify as a comment to the OP.

Comment: @MoisheKohan. I see the problem. I misunderstood the question and now, I realice that this is far to be a good answer. Thank you for make me notice it. I wanted to delete my answer, however I can't because it was accepted.

Answer (score 3):

If you include the case $r=0$ then *this is a topology*.  It's the discrete topology where all singletons of points are open.

If you exclude the case $r=0$, the collection of closed balls don't necessarily constitute a base for a topology, because the intersection of two closed balls can be one point.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the set of closed balls (closed in the sense of a given metric $\rho$) *does* constitute a basis for a topology on $X$. You can easily show this: for any $x \in X$, the closed ball $C_\rho (x, 1)$ contains $x$. Suppose that the intersection of $C_\rho (y, \delta)$ and $C_\rho (z, \varepsilon)$ includes $x$. The basis element $C_\rho (x, \min \{ \delta - \rho (x, y), \varepsilon - \rho (x, z) \}) \subseteq C_\rho (y, \delta) \cap C_\rho (z, \varepsilon)$ also contains $x$.

However, the topology induced by this basis of closed balls is *not* the same as the topology induced by the metric $\rho$. Indeed, the new topology is the *discrete* topology on $X$, because each singleton $\{ x \} = C_\rho (x, 0)$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

If you define closed balls strictly, that is, if $B_r(x_0)=\{x: d(x,x_0)\leq r\}$ is a closed ball for $\color{red}{r>0}$, then the set of closed balls does not constitute a basis for a topology.

For example, consider $\Bbb R^2$ and its set of closed balls $\cal C$ in Euclidean metric. Let $A=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2\leq\tfrac14\}$ and $B=\{(x,y): (x-1)^2+y^2\leq\tfrac14\}$. They are closed balls. But $A\cap B=\{(1,0)\}$ is not a closed ball. Therefore, $\cal C$ is not a topological basis according to the definition of topological basis.